# ggplot2 and GLM: plot a predicted probability

Tags: r, ggplot2, glm

I am looking for some help as to how you make a ggplot with the following data. There are several examples on stackoverflow, but they are a lot more complicated and I am having trouble figuring it out.

```
library(car)
data(Chile)
Chile$yes <- with(Chile, ifelse(vote == "Y", 1, ifelse(vote=="N", 0, NA))) 
Chile<-na.omit(Chile)

logit1 <- glm(yes ~ statusquo + age + income + sex, data = Chile, family=binomial(link="logit")) 


inject1 <- data.frame(statusquo=mean(na.omit(Chile$statusquo)), income=mean(Chile$income), sex="F", age=mean(Chile$age))
predict1 <- predict(logit1, newdata=inject1, type="response", se.fit=TRUE)


inject2 <- data.frame(statusquo=mean(na.omit(Chile$statusquo)), income=mean(Chile$income), sex="M", age=mean(Chile$age))
predict2 <- predict(logit1, newdata=inject2, type="response", se.fit=TRUE)
```

The outcome variable is "yes", x would be different in sex I suppose - I would like to plot the predictions.

Thanks in advance for your time and help!

Comment: You only have one prediction. What exactly do you want to plot? What would be the `x` and `y` axes?

Comment: Updated with another if this helps? Sorry I am not that great with plotting GLM.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the typical "S" shaped plot of logistic regression you need more predictions rather 
than point prediction which you are employing currently

```
install.packages("caret")

library(car)
library(ggplot2)

data(Chile)
Chile$yes <- with(Chile, ifelse(vote == "Y", 1, ifelse(vote=="N", 0, NA))) 
Chile<-na.omit(Chile)
```

In order to have more predictions, we split the dataset into training and testing dataset using `createDataPartition` function from `caret` package

```
#split Chile dataset into train for fitting and test for prediction purpose
set.seed(42)
trainIndex = createDataPartition(Chile$yes, p=0.75,list=FALSE)


trainChile = Chile[trainIndex,]
testChile = Chile[-trainIndex,]

#fit logit model
fitLogit <- glm(yes ~ statusquo + age + income + sex, data = trainChile, family=binomial(link="logit")) 

#predict on test data
predLogit <- predict(fitLogit, newdata=testChile, type="response", se.fit=TRUE)
```

**Plotting**

I have plotted the outcome variable vs one predictor "statusquo".
You could adapt this for other predictors by changing the index of `predictorVec`

```
#if fit value is > 0.5, we consider voting outcome as "YES/1 else  "NO"/0

predictorVec = c("statusquo","age","income","sex")

x = predictorVec[1]

plotObj= data.frame(predictor=testChile[,x],outcome=ifelse(predLogit$fit>0.5,1,0))

gg = ggplot(plotObj, aes(x=predictor, y= outcome)) + geom_point() + 
  stat_smooth(method="glm", method.args=list(family="binomial"), se=FALSE) + 
  ggtitle(paste0("Prediction for predictor:",x)) +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(size=14, face="bold"))
print(gg)
```

[image]